# How do I install libxml on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, ide

In the process of trying to install the Cloud9 IDE. I have major issues installing `libxml`. Is anyone else having similar problems?

Comment: What "major issues"? Are you following a specific set of instructions? Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: Im trying to install cloud9ide onto my raspberryPi, im following the github readme instructions that say  "sm clone --dev https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/tree/master cloud9" but it fails with the libxml thing (trying to get some meaningfull error messages together now....) i then found [this](http://ian-corbitt.com/cloud9-ide-and-nodejs-v0-6-15-on-beaglebone/) which talks about building the xml module into the cloud9 source manually so that you can remove the one command line arg that is giving me all the grief, but source-mint and this approach don't seem to go well together

Answer (score 6):

Turns out the `Node.js` folks made [precompiled binaries available for the `Raspberry Pi`](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.17/node-v0.8.17-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz).

Here's how I installed `Cloud9` on `Debian wheezy` on my `Raspberry Pi`.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential openssl libssl-dev pkg-config libxml2-dev
cd ~
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.17/node-v0.8.17-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz
cd /usr/local
sudo tar xzvf ~/node-v0.8.17-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz --strip=1
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules"
sudo npm install -g sm
sudo chown -Rf 1000:1000 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sm
git clone https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9.git cloud9
cd cloud9 && mkdir node_modules && cd node_modules
git clone https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-libxml.git libxml
cd libxml && git checkout v0.0.7 && git submodule init && git submodule update
nano support/o3/wscript
```

Delete the `-msse2` options, save and exit `nano`.

```
sudo npm install -g
cd ~/cloud9
sudo npm install
```

Compiling `libxml` took 17-18 minutes. The rest of it took may be a hour.

To run `Cloud9`,

```
bin/cloud9.sh -l 0.0.0.0
```

Then on any browser, go to `http://<raspberry-pi-ip-address>:3131/`.

Answer (score 2):

With no more information, I'll still try to answer.

Did you try to install [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) with the following command?

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

Comment: +1. I think "libxml" is referring to a [javascript wrapper](http://github.com/ajaxorg/node-libxml.git); of which, libxml2-dev will need to be installed on the base system.

Comment: Thanks for everyone replies, yes i believe that the error i got was for the npm module libxml. i left a [issue](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-libxml/issues/7) on the github repo for the module.  @emcconville, thanks for that sugestion ill try it now. . . .